# Assign file to image compile error: javax.imageio.IIOException

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to assign an image as a background with swing. I've found multiple ways to do this, but I always seem to run into the same problem. I found a nice custom class to use here > http://www.camick.com/java/source/BackgroundPanel.java

Here is the code I'm using...

*Edit Code: Added Constructor*

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestMain {
    TestMain(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        Image img = null;
        File f = new File("../images/Background.png");
        img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(f));
        System.out.println("File " + f.toString());


        BackgroundPanel background = new BackgroundPanel(img, BackgroundPanel.SCALED, 0.50f, 0.5f);

        frame.setContentPane(background);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        new TestMain();
    }
}
```

And here is what the image looks like...

[image]

When I try to run this code, I get a compile error `Error:(14, 51) java: incompatible types: java.io.File cannot be converted to java.lang.String`. If anyone could figure out how to help me do this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: The error is self explanatory, the file can not be found.  The question is, where is the file stored in relationship to the project and class files, from where is the code been executed, in relationship to where the file is stored

Comment: In the same project, this is the line of code I'm using to make the image show up for a label (same location), and it works > `charImgLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(image)).getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, "../images/Character.png".SCALE_SMOOTH)));`

Comment: Then `img = ImageIO.read(f);` should read `img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(image));` - I'd also like to point out that the code you just posted won't compile as `Image#getScaledImage`'s `hint` property is an `int` and not a `String` ... so, I have no idea

Comment: hmmm, I suppose that would make sense, but now I'm getting the error `Non-static method getClass() cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: Because you're doing all your work from within `main`, which doesn't have a class instance to work with.  You could try using `TestMainnet.class` instead, although it might give different results, this is why I don't like working in `static` contexts :P

Comment: So I threw all the code into a constructor `TestMain()` (also edited the code to match in question). The only line I have in my main function now is `new TestMain();`. That error went away, but now I'm getting the error `Error:(14, 51) java: incompatible types: java.io.File cannot be converted to java.lang.String`. This is for the `(f)` in line `img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(f));`. Also, sorry for the question bombardments, I'm kinda new at this...

Comment: Don't use `f` use the `String` file, I assume you assigned to `image`, if your previous snippet with `ImageIcon` worked, then the same value should work for `ImageIO` (using `getResource`)

Comment: hmm, so I have to use `throws IOException` in both `TestMain() throws IOException` and `public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException` to get this line to work `img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("../images/Background.png"));`. This seems like a very unclean way to add a background image. I wish there was an easier way... Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: The fact that `ImageIO` throws an exception is one of it's greatest feature, because at least now you know why your image isn't loading rather than it failing silently like `ImageIcon` does.  Personally, I'd wrap the exception around the code which is most responsible for handling it and dealing with the exception in an appropriate manner

Comment: Great suggestion, I'll definitely look more into this. You rock :)

Comment: Yup, it looks like the `Try{} Catch(Exception e){}` is the best way to avoid using `throws IOException`. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the same project, this is the line of code I'm using to make the image show up for a label (same location), and it works > `charImgLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(image)).getImag‌​e().getScaledInstanc‌​e(100, 100, "../images/Character.png".SCALE_SMOOTH)));`

Okay, let's just look past the obvious compiler error there for a second.

I assume that `image` is a `String` reference to the path of the image within the current classloader context, meaning that

```
img = ImageIO.read(f);
```

should actually be

```
img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(image));
```

Assuming that the image is stored within the classloader context (ie the Jar/classpath) and the path you've specified is correct, then this should load your image